# programatically hide a bone in pose mode and in edit mode

Tags: python, armature, bones

I would like to create a function that hides the selected bones in pose mode and in Edit mode.

The easy way to go is certainly:

- set the armature to EDIT mode
- set the hide flag for the selected edit_bones
- set the armature to POSE mode
- the hide flag for the selected bones

Instead of hiding bones i theoretically could move them to another hidden bone layer. However this does not work in my case for a couple of reasons, so this is not an option for me.

However i want to avoid calling operators and i also want to avoid changing the armature mode, So i wonder if there is a more elegant way to hide bones without need to enter edit mode or pose mode at all and without calling operators?

Comment: AFAIK there's no way to access edit_bones without going into EDIT mode. You can change the regular Bone.hide flag from any mode though, you don't need to be in POSE mode. But if the arma was already in EDIT mode, the edit_bones and regular bones are not necessarily "in sync", so you have to exit EDIT mode anyway to make them sync up.

Comment: @scurest While you can change the pose bone hide state in any mode, the change will only work if you do it in POSE mode, so you need at least two mode changes and up to 3.  If you're in OBJECT mode you need something like ->POSE->EDIT->OBJECT

Comment: @MartyFouts "the change will only work if you do it in POSE mode" What do you mean? I'm testing it in OBJECT mode and it's working for me.

Comment: Have you checked in POSE to see that the bone hides? On 3.2.1 the OBJECT mode setting doesn’t propagate, at least not in my test.

Comment: @MartyFouts arma.bones[x].hide controls it for both OBJECT and POSE mode for me.

Comment: ah.  I was trying `object.pose.bones`.  That only works in POSE mode but appears to work in OBJECT mode.